# Difference between amplitude modulation and intensity modulation

Tags: laser, frequency

If a few kHz modulation is imposed on the 80MHz pulse train of a laser by the means  of either a Mch-Zehnder interferometer or a single acousto optical modulator triggered by an external function generator, what kind of modulation is taking place? Amplitude modulation or intensity modulation?

Comment: modulation in amplitude leads to modulation in intensity, so is there some important difference that you are thinking about (nonlinearity)?

Comment: "If a few kHz modulation" this is frequency modulation and it does not affect (much) the amplitude or the intensity ( which is a function of average amplitude) https://www.pbs.org/wgbh/aso/tryit/radio/radiorelayer.html  em waves have the same mathematical description  for all frequencies.

Comment: @AmIAStudent Actually your answer better rephrases my question. "modulation of amplitude leads to modulation in intensity". So the question is still under normal circumstances is amplitude modulation same to intensity modulation or is there a fine difference between these two?

Comment: @annav actually this few kHz is significant. So much so that I am using this as a reference for my lock in amplifier to extract signals.

Comment: amplitude of electromagnetic waves is conventionally described by the E field, a time varying vector.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation#Properties . intensity is given by the average of the amplitude as the Poynting vector http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Waves/emwv.html

Comment: @user188062 Did you end up clarifying your own question? I'm stuck on this myself, and am trying to figure out, if a MZI, is performing amplitude or intensity modulation myself, and am not sure about what the subtle differences of the two are.

Comment: I've found a book which clearly explains the action of an MZI. It's "Fiber Optic Measurement Techniques" by Hui and O'Sullivan. An MZI indeed an intensity modulator. The MZI does also modulate the field vector sinusoidally, but also phase modulates the field as well. As intensity is the square of the field, I *believe* the phase modulation should be undetectable when measuring the intensity, but should be detectable if your taking an amplitude measurement, such as one with a homodyne detector.

Answer (score 1):

The usage difference reflects the essentially noise-like nature of laser light relative to the modulation rate. The word intensity means average power, that is the variance of instantaneous amplitude, and is preferred when the underlying modulation is very slow relative to the natural fluctuation rate. The average instantaneous light amplitude is zero and in that sense it is just like RF thermal noise and it stays that way even when the mean square amplitude, ie., the intensity is modulated.

In amplitude modulation of a sinusoidal carrier there is a non-zero "amplitude" that is being changed at some rate much smaller than the carrier frequency. This also modulates the intensity, ie., the average power of the carrier but from an engineer's point of view it is usually done by a multiplicative process (heterodyning) instead of source bias modulation or by a variable attenuator as is more applicable for a laser source. Both bias modulation and variable attenuator can be used  in RF but they are noisy and rather lossy when compared to mixing/heterodyning. Making a laser source somewhat noisier by bias modulation makes no difference in practice, not so for your AM radio...

Comment: I second it. +1

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old and I know I left a comment but I wanted to slightly concretely add to my comment about MZI intensity modulators with some maths. Specifically from [this](https://www.intechopen.com/chapters/60637) paper.

They give the general form for the optical scattering trasnfer matrix of an MZI as:

[image]

By applying a modulating signal, to the MZI we change delta phi. If it acted as an amplitude modulator, you would just have the part within the brackets, i.e. the amplitude output would depend of the phase difference between the two branches delta phi and that would be the sole action. However, there is also a phase modulation - the term outside the brackets. This is undetectable when doing an intenisty measurement with a photodiode, however it will be detectable if detecting with a coherent receiver such as a homodyne detector.

TLDR: A MZI intensity modulator, is not a amplitude modulator, although it does modulate amplitude, it also applys a phase modulation.